# How do I setup a Android MQTT project using ia92 wmqtt.jar?

Tags: android, mqtt

I have been trying to implement an MQTT service using wmqtt.jar. 
Like most folks I started with looking at other peoples examples.
I found several references to Dale Lane's post http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=1599 and downloaded a version of his service from http://mosquitto.org/2011/11/android-mqtt-example-project/.
My problem is that every example I try to run that uses wmqtt.jar in my emulator the code crashes as soon as any class that references MqttSimpleCallback with ajava.lang.ClassNotFoundException. Is there something "special" I have to do to make this run?
Normally I would assume the problem is with my code, but since all the examples from other sources I have tried crashes with the same problem, I have to assume I have missed something in my setup?

Here is what my LogCat looks like when the code from mosquitto.org blows up.

```
04-13 21:48:59.447: D/AndroidRuntime(303): Shutting down VM
04-13 21:48:59.447: W/dalvikvm(303): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-13 21:48:59.548: E/AndroidRuntime(303): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 21:48:59.548: E/AndroidRuntime(303): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.mosquitto.android.mqttdemo/org.mosquitto.android.mqttdemo.MQTTDemo}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mosquitto.android.mqttdemo.MQTTDemo in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/org.mosquitto.android.mqttdemo-2.apk]
04-13 21:48:59.548: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
04-13 21:48:59.548: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-13 21:48:59.548: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-13 21:48:59.548: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-13 21:48:59.548: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-13 21:48:59.548: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-13 21:48:59.548: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-13 21:48:59.548: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 21:48:59.548: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-13 21:48:59.548: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-13 21:48:59.548: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-13 21:48:59.548: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native  Method)
04-13 21:48:59.548: E/AndroidRuntime(303): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mosquitto.android.mqttdemo.MQTTDemo in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/org.mosquitto.android.mqttdemo-2.apk]
04-13 21:48:59.548: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
04-13 21:48:59.548: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
04-13 21:48:59.548: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
04-13 21:48:59.548: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-13 21:48:59.548: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
04-13 21:48:59.548: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you use the Paho Java client library available from http://git.eclipse.org/c/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java.git/ It's not the same code base as ia92 but the licence is much friendlier.

ia92 is no longer developed or supported, as mentioned on http://mqtt.org/software

Comment: I have started trying to use the Paho Java client, but I am having problems setting it up correctly as well and there is NO documentation that I can find. Instead of the ClassNotFoundError, I am getting a ClassDefNotFound error. I am willing to use either library if I can get one to run.

Comment: I confess I've not used it myself. The place to ask about it is https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/paho-dev

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you copy the wmqtt.jar and any libraries it might require into your libs directory. Then rebuild it and push it to your emulator.

Missing jar files are a big reason that class def not found exceptions happen.

Comment: I have made sure that wmqtt.jar is in my libs directory and added the jar to my Java Build Path under Libraries. Not sure how to know what the wmqtt.jar requires?

Comment: Do you have the java docs for the jar, or can you open the jar and verify that the class mentioned as being not found is contained in that jar file?

Comment: No the jar does not have java docs or source. It does have html help with the package that it came in, but that only tells what is suppose to be in the jar, not what is actually in the jar.

Comment: unzip the jar file and look for the .class file. It doesn't matter if the file contents are readable, you're just trying to verify that it is in your project.

Comment: I can find the class when I unzip the jar.

Comment: Okay Chuck. I put the a copy of my log cat up there.

Comment: So, making sure that org.mosquitto.android.mqttdemo.MQTTDemo is in that jar file will be the key to what to do next. Everything up until the MQTTDemo will be the directory structure, with the final file name being MQTTDemo.class

Answer (score 0):

Using eclipse? find the jar in your package explorer, right click it, then choose "Build Path" => "Add To Build path". try again?