# Build Failed with Gradle

Tags: android, events, gradle

Good morning everyone, 
Today, I have try to modify an old application with the new Android plugin v1.0.1 and it make a build failed for a unknow reason:

On a activity, i have 2 button which make an Alert Dialog: 
In the first, I have the following function and it's really good:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Oui", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    @override 
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialof,int which){
        broadcastOptServ("clear","clear");
        }
    });
```

And i want have a similar struct for the second but grable make me a Build failed if i make :

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Oui", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    @override 
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialof,int which){
        broadcastOptServ("Ack","Ack");
        }
    });
```

So it's ok with that :

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Oui", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    @override 
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialof,int which){
        new Thread(new runnable(){
            @override 
            public void run(){
                broadcastOptServ("Ack","Ack");
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
```

Why grable doesn't like the first struct ? 
The Error it make is :

```
 FAILURE : Build failed with an exception. 
 *What went wrong
 Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
 com.android.ide.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command: 
 C:\....\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex -- incremental --no-strict --output
 C:\....\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list = C:\...\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
 Error Code:
      2
  Output: 

       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION
       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/ibm/mqtt/IMqttClient
          com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
          com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
          com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
          com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
          com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
          com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
          com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
          com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
          com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
          com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 10
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'org.mosquitto.android.SupTel'
        targetSdkVersion 10
        minSdkVersion 10
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        //preDexLibraries =false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('ia92/J2SE/wmqtt.jar')
}
```

And I have an other issue: When I try to use by button "Ack", the broadcast is never send ... why ? (All of that was good before I update Android Studio --')

Thank's for time ;)

Sorry for my English...

Comment: post your *build.gradle* file

Comment: Your problems seems to be related to the MQTT library and its compilation it seems to be defined multiple times at least for * IMqttClient*, Have you tried a project clean and build ?
Also it seems the ia92 mqtt library you're using is discontinued check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145464/how-do-i-setup-a-android-mqtt-project-using-ia92-wmqtt-jar where they recommend an alternative if that suits you

Comment: Yes , just before , i have a thing like that but i haven't find the double reporting about the class. When i delete the library , it's make me a NotClassDefFound exception. So now, i have just one compile files and i dont know where i can delete the other. I go see topic

Comment: If i understand good , my library ia92 isn't longer compatible with Android Studio, so i must to past on Paho library ?

Comment: They just say its discontinued meaning no longer maintained by anyone.

Comment: how i can keep maintained the ia92 library to my project ?